# PyTest logger does not show any output when if all tests are selected to run

Tags: python, pytest

I am using pytest-logger==0.5.1 to print logs on console and insert into log files.

Following is the directory structure -

```
    .
    ├── catalog
    │   └── tests
    │       ├── conftest.py
    │       ├── test_create.py
    │       └── test_update.py
    └── run_tasks.py
```

conftest.py

```
def pytest_logger_config(logger_config):
    if os.environ.get('VERBOSE') == 'True':
        import logging
        logger = logging.getLogger('Log')
        logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        stdout = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
        logger.addHandler(stdout)
    else:
        logger_config.add_loggers(['Log'], stdout_level='debug')
        logger_config.set_log_option_default('Log')

def pytest_logger_logsdir(config):
    return os.path.join(os.environ.get('OUTPUT_DIR'), 'logs')
```

test_create.py

```
import pytest
import logging
Log = logging.getLogger('Log')


class TestCreateAsset():
    @pytest.mark.parametrize("x, y", [("a", "b")], indirect=["x"])
    def test_indirect(self, x, y):
        Log.info("xxxx")
        Log.info("yyyy")
        assert x == "aaa"
        assert y == "b"
```

run_tasks.py

```
import os
import pytest
cmd1 = ["pytest", "-s", "-v", "--html-report", "./report.html", "catalog/tests/test_create.py"]
cmd2 = ["pytest", "-s", "-v", "--html-report", "./report.html"]

os.environ['VERBOSE'] = True
#return pytest.main(cmd1)
return pytest.main(cmd2)
```

When I execute cmd1 from run_task.py pytest-logger generates console/verbose output.

When I execute cmd2 from run_task.py pytest-logger does not generate console/verbose output and also not creating log files. The pytest hook pytest_logger_config doesn't get executed.

Comment: Cmd2 isn’t running any tests

Comment: It executes all the test scripts and methods

Comment: probably you need to put conftest.py into the main directory or use "catalog/tests" as a parameter for cmd2